# how can I handle negative parantheses while converting infix expressions to postfix expression?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, stack, expression

When I try to convert infix expression to postfix expression,
`3*(3+6/2)`

it will be converted to like this.
`3362/+*`

My problem is this, how can I handle if there is negative sign in front of parantheses? Like
`3*-(3+6/2)` or `3*(-(3+6/2))`

When I try to convert these to postfix expressions, it would be like
`3*362/+-` and `3362/+-*`, but none of these expressions are valid: I cannot calculate these expressions in common way which we use to calculate postfix expressions.

So is there any way to handle these?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17132657/16466946) address your problem?

Comment: Or perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20246787/56778)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [handling unary minus for shunting-yard algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246787/handling-unary-minus-for-shunting-yard-algorithm)