# java -negative unary operator in RPN algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, javafx, negative-number

i got a problem with negative unary operator - i do not know how to implement it in my code, can someone help me do this? I got whole calculator written in java fx everything works fine, but i need to implement feature that allows user to calculate expression like: -5 + 3 * 8 or 3 + 2 * (-8).
Waiting for your answer,
regards

Comment: Your problem seems the fact that you didn't implement anything related to unary operators at all. You need to distinguish an unary minus from a binary minus so that the conversion is done correctly and the evaluator just pops a single value instead that two. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593080/how-can-i-modify-my-shunting-yard-algorithm-so-it-accepts-unary-operators

Comment: thank you Jack for your kind help i've managed my problem;)